# How to place a required field validator inside a GridView TextBox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a `GridView` with some `TemplateField` items containing `TextBox` controls. I would like to add a required field validator on it. This is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="vid">
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtvid" runat="server" Width="150px"
                            Text='<%# Bind("vid") %>'>
         </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label 
                   ID="lblvid" runat="server" 
                   Text='<%# Bind("vid") %>'>
         </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

How do I place a required field validator on `txtvid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Edit template, add a `RequiredFieldValidator` like this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtvid" 
                 runat="server" Width="150px"
                 Text='<%# Bind("vid") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                 ControlToValidate="txtvid" 
                 runat="server" 
                 ErrorMessage="Please enter a 'vid' number" 
                 Text="*"/>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Here is the reference for the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

**UPDATE:**

If you wanted a regular expression validator, its pretty much the same, but with the `RegularExpressionValidator` control:

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
     ControlToValidate="txtvid"
     ValidationExpression="\d{10}"
     runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Please enter a 'vid' of 10 digits" 
     Text="*"/>
```

Here is a complete list of the functionality for the [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: basically i use regular expression validator and already try that code by my self by it not working

Comment: required field validator is working fine but regular expression is not working here

Comment: @amitesh: But your question is: _"how to put required field validation inside gridview textbox"_

Comment: sry guys but yes dominiz your code work i use regularexpression validator and it work thanks mate and thank tim

Answer (score 1):

Within gridview i assign textbox,requiredfieldvalidator and button,This validator validate all textboxes in gridview when button click without  filling textbox. How can i solve this..

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="vid">               
        <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtvid" runat="server" Width="150px" ValidationGroup ="subgrp">
             </asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvQuantity" ControlToValidate="txtvid" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red"
                    ValidationGroup = "subgrp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
             <asp:Label 
                       ID="lblvid" runat="server" 
                       Text='<%# Bind("vid") %>'>
             </asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" ValidationGroup ="subgrp"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

This will validate all textboxs in gridview,When i click button in particular row without filling the textbox in itemtemplate.

Comment: Set your button attribute CauseValidation = "false" .Because it is default true.