# DataGridView Error System.FormatException on writing Symbos/letters

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following DataGridview that  requires to write only integer number, however if users writes any symbols/letter this error is promted. BTW this column is loaded from a database and value will be always an integer(so the entire columns is only for number only), so i dont know how to validate numbers when the users is editing the rows and not show this error.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value != null)
        {

            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value == System.DBNull.Value || dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value == null)//Check if cell is not nulll
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
            else
            {
                int numero;
                string mimonto = string.Empty + this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value;
                bool res = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < mimonto.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (char.IsNumber(mimonto[i]) == true)// if position is a number
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res = false;//value is not a number
                    }
                }

                if (res == true)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.White; //this is a number and color stays as white
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;//color is red if it's not a number 

                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = 0;
                    MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar valores númericos");




                }

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the error when a symbol/letter or anything thats not a number.

[image]

BTW is there any option to enable only number writting on cell? or is there any better option to solve this error?

Comment: Try if the link below help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273141/regex-for-numbers-only

Comment: It worked fine to validate numbers, but the error still is promted when the users write any symbol/letters.

Comment: You can use a RegularExpressionValidator. Try it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131992/how-to-place-a-required-field-validator-inside-a-gridview-textbox

Comment: it's winforms, not asp.net to use regular expression validator. Is it possible to use something like on window forms?